How to refresh Spring Actuator response at runetime?
Is it possible to get a refreshed response from the Spring Actuator endpoint (e.g. https://localhost:8080/app/actuator/env) while the application is running?
For example, on the AWS Parameter Store the parameter “app.actuator.excludedEndpoints” is empty, so the endpoint app/actuator/env should return the correct response (and it does).
But when I meanwhile change the value for “app.actuator.excludedEndpoints” to env and use “/refresh-actuator-config” I actually see in the debugger that it refreshes the Bean “webEndpointProperties” is refreshed and excludedEndpoints has a new value but in the response for “/app/actuator/env” I get still the previous response (I should get an error!).
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class ManagementConfig {

  @Value("${app.actuator.excludedEndpoints}")
  private String excludedEndpoints;

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @RefreshScope
  public WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties() {
    return createWebEndpointProperties();
  }

  private WebEndpointProperties createWebEndpointProperties() {
    WebEndpointProperties properties = new WebEndpointProperties();
    properties.setBasePath("/app/actuator");

    Set<String> excludedEndpointsSet = Set.of(excludedEndpoints.split(","));

    properties.getExposure().setExclude(excludedEndpointsSet);
    return properties;
  }

  @Bean
  public WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping webFluxEndpointHandlerMapping(
      WebEndpointDiscoverer endpointDiscoverer) {

    EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping("/app/actuator");
    Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> endpoints = endpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints();
    EndpointMediaTypes mediaTypes = EndpointMediaTypes.DEFAULT;
    EndpointLinksResolver linksResolver = new EndpointLinksResolver(endpoints);

    return new WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping(
        endpointMapping,
        endpoints,
        mediaTypes,
        null,
        linksResolver,
        true
    );
  }

  public void refreshWebEndpointProperties() {
    DefaultListableBeanFactory beanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) applicationContext.getBeanFactory();

    // Force environment refresh
    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    environment.getPropertySources().iterator();

    // Refresh web properties
    beanFactory.destroySingleton("webEndpointProperties");
    beanFactory.registerSingleton("webEndpointProperties", createWebEndpointProperties());

    // Refresh handler mapping
    beanFactory.destroySingleton("webFluxEndpointHandlerMapping");
    applicationContext.getBean("webFluxEndpointHandlerMapping");
  }
}

Refresh controller:
@RestController
public class ConfigRefreshController {

  @Qualifier("configDataContextRefresher")
  @Autowired
  private ContextRefresher contextRefresher;

  @Autowired
  private ManagementConfig managementConfig;

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

  @PostMapping("/refresh-actuator-config")
  public String refreshConfig() {
    contextRefresher.refresh();
    managementConfig.refreshWebEndpointProperties();
    return "Configuration refreshed";
  }
}

In addition, I do not know if this is relevant, but I use reactive Netty.
